# How can I get hover over to display inherited code for python classes in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, inheritance, docstring

I have written a base repository and cookiecutter that defines abstract django models and other helpers for celery workflow systems.

The aim was to standardise the workflows we create and keep them small so they are simple and each one is familiar to the next.

I'd like developers on the downstream workflow systems to easily see the docstrings that the child model they are working on inherits from the parent but other than including all the inherited stuff in the docstring I'm low on ideas. Docstring inheritance and the docstring inheritance package https://pypi.org/project/docstring-inheritance/ seems to offer some help but this feels like it will be more useful where the developer docs are built rather than in the ide.

It would be nice if we could have something available in the ide other than clicking through to the base class, but the only way I can think to do this is with hover over docstrings.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to set these up in such a way that they actually inherit anything. At the moment my docstring-inheritance example works in ipython but the hover over does not reflect the output I see when I set it up in ipython

ipython Example

```
from docstring_inheritance import GoogleDocstringInheritanceMeta
   
class Test(metaclass=GoogleDocstringInheritanceMeta):
   """This is test 1.
   
       Attributes:
           test 1
   """

class Result(Test):
    """This is test 2."""

Result.__doc__
Out[4]: 'This is test 2.\n\nAttributes:\n    test 1'
```

This vscode ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsBX4.png)) show's me hovering over the child class and only seeing the child class docstring

In an ideal world I would expect the hover over to show the child class docstring intro and the parent class attributes section as occurs in the ipython example

Comment: ..but you can also hover over `Test` in the inheritance part (inside the brackets) and see its doc string.  So you can already do this !

Comment: It would be too clutterred and noisy seeing parent, children doc strings. And if that was the case, if there was **multiple inheritance**, that concept would be very messy...

Comment: @D.L. You are right about hovering over Test and I did realise that - albeit partway through drafting the question. I think both are pretty messy tbh. I'd prefer to see only the attributes on the child class and forego the option to see what's on the parent class.  I suppose my ideal option would be for the ide to add in the actual docstring in a way that could expand (but obvs not be edited) - but I guess if I want that I'll need to build it :-D. Thanks for the speedy response.

Comment: I think you'd need to [write a feature-request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/new?assignees=&labels=classify%2C+feature-request&projects=&template=3_feature_request.md). If you do, please ping me with a link to it.